# activemq message redelivery

Tags: activemq-classic

I would like to know whether it is possible to retain one message in the queue without it getting re-delivered by activemq after one consumption for a certain time i.e message m1 once consumed and the session is closed. I want m1 not to be re delivered by activemq for some some time. After the time it can be re-delivered.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Arijit

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps http://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html